# unable to start hsql database

Tags: hsqldb

I'm trying to start the hsqldb using this command:

```
java -classpath ..\war\WEB-INF\lib\hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server -database test
```

This is taken from http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part5.html - section "5.1. Create database startup script"

This is the error I get:

```
C:\Projects3\springapp\db>java -classpath ..\war\WEB-INF\lib\hsqldb.jar org.hsql
db.Server -database
[Server@e0e1c6]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
[Server@e0e1c6]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
[Server@e0e1c6]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: Failed to set properties
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1937)
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1904)
        at org.hsqldb.server.ServerProperties.validateMultiProperty(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at org.hsqldb.server.ServerProperties.validate(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.server.Server.setProperties(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.server.Server.main(Unknown Source)
```

Is this not the correct way to start a hsql database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
java -classpath ..\war\WEB-INF\lib\hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server --database.0 test
```

Comment: That worked, but I dont know why? what is the difference between "database" and "--database.0"

Comment: "--database" is an alias for "--database.0" when there is only one database. A glitch is causing the error in the particular version of HSQLDB that you tried.